# OSX - Conditionally block outgoing connection to web service, based on wifi network / LAN connection

Tags: macos, networking, dns

I've got a cloud backup programme that I'd like to only run when connected to one particular wifi network / LAN. As the other networks I connect to regularly dont have another bandwidth to backup the computer over the internet.

I've been thinking of ways to Block / Allow outgoing connection to select services / sites based on what LAN / wireless network your connected to, and have looked at some GUI apps such as [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) and [Tripmode](http://tripmode.ch), but these both work on the principal of blocking all outgoing connections and having you manually approve each new connection, they also let you do this on a per network basis.

Really I just want to block 1 outgoing connection, which got me thinking of ways to do this, could i add the site / service i want to block to my DNS block list, but only have it triggered conditionally when connected to a pre defined wifi network / LAN (I can't do this on an external IP basis as I have a dynamic IP at the site where I want to backup from).

I'm running OSX 10.10.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like [Control plane](https://www.controlplaneapp.com/feature-list/) to run script on location change.

The script, for example, can add a line to `/etc/hosts` with the backup endpoint address pointing to localhost.